# Windows 10 can compile C programs with gcc but will not run

Tags: c, gcc, cmd

I installed gcc on my Windows 10 PC and can compile C code into an exe from the command prompt eg.

```
gcc HelloWorld.c -o HelloWorld
```

however when I try to run using

```
HelloWorld
```

the program will run however nothing will be output and it won't do anything

This is the C program that I compile and run that does nothing which doesn't have any errors that I can see

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {

printf("Hello from C!");

return 0;
}
```

Can someone point out whats happening?

Comment: line buffering. printf("Hello from C!\n");

Comment: what do you mean line buffering? adding \n gives me the same result?

Comment: @Joe When main returns all streams are flushed automatically. 7.21.3.p5

Comment: Interesting. Usually the output to stdout of printf is buffered (not displayed) until a newline is sent. The \n should give a newline and force the output to be displayed.

Comment: @2501 Dammit. True. That'll teach me for knee-jerk responses!

Comment: It's happening with any c program that I write however my surface running Windows 10 as well runs the same programs with no problem

Comment: If you run `HelloWorld >> trace.txt`  what is written in trace.txt file?

Comment: It runs and does nothing like usual and the trace.txt file is blank

Comment: @Marcel How did you install gcc? Is it a variant of MinGW?

Comment: yea from mingw.org then added mingw\bin to the Path

Comment: If you run it typing `.\HelloWorld` instead of `HelloWorld` does it work ?

Comment: Have you got different anti-virus configurations on your PC and your surface?

Comment: Nothing that I think would affect running a hello world program, anything specifically?

Comment: @Marcel I suspect the program you tried to run is not compiled from the source above, better double check.

Comment: I've compiled and tried running like 5 programs even running a program that was compiled on my surface and the same thing happens

Comment: Can you ommit the extension (`.exe`) in Windows?

Comment: whether or not I include .exe in the compilation or execution I still get the same result

Comment: The problem can't be reproduced. Are you sure that the problem isn't that you don't see the console window before it closes? That is, add `getchar` at the end.

Comment: I tried adding a scanf however when it starts running any program it won't allow me to type anything

Comment: Finally figured out it was Avast blocking the programs from running the whole time

Answer (score 1):

Compile your source code by:

```
gcc HelloWorld.c -o ./HelloWorld.exe
```

and then run it by:

```
./HelloWorld.exe
```

If it still fails, you can run `dir` to see what's in your current directory.

Comment: With that for some reason it said '.' is not recognized as an internal or external command